# Why can't I click on META when using the latest version of Chrome on Win10?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta

On every other site on Stack Exchange I can click on the site's title and be taken directly to the questions...

> Except Meta.stackexchange.com

Here I actually have to click on the word "Questions" as there is no link active on the Meta title and logo.

Now I agree this isn't a big deal, however as I typically visit stack exchange pages up to a couple of hundred times a day, this one that doesn't fit spoils my flow. I am pretty certain it used to work.

It works for me in Firefox, and Safari on iPad, but even closing and reopening Chrome doesn't fix the issue.

Chrome is on Version 53.0.2785.116

Comment: I can click on META. IOW, something's wrong.

Comment: It's working for me right now. The logo and name are a link to `meta.stackexchange.com`

Comment: weird - it's only this site, and only in Chrome. Oh well, it's obviously a 'me' problem so I'll hunt around for what is weird here...

Comment: Works on my machine... Windows 8.1, Chrome 53

Comment: It occurs to me that we should automatically extract the user agent string from the request when folks post bugs, and offer to add it to the question for them. Your browser is a hair more up-to-date than mine; I'll update & then - if still unreproduced - mark it so.

Comment: I've added version anyway - I should have done that first off...

Comment: norepro same Chrome version (OS X 10.11.6)

Comment: I've had this problem too for the past couple of days. I just assumed it was a temporary glitch in Chrome and have instead been opening the Stack Exchange menu to access a link to the homepage. Also only happens here on Meta for me.

Comment: oooooh - so not just me then? wondering if I should blame jquery... :-)

Comment: @RoryAlsop I can't imagine why it'd be related, but it could be. The elements are in the correct position and the link is *there*, but for some reason I cannot click on it. Removing the `text-indent` so the text is not off-screen does make the entire element clickable for me again, but it also leaves ugly text on top of the logo.

Comment: Reproduced on ChromeOS 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit)

Comment: With the newnav, for a while, this was actually by design... Though I doubt it's related, I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Reproduced with Chrome 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit) on Fedora 24.

Comment: Dorukayhan - no. The only user script I have is one for chat...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strange this is happening only here on MSE.

The reason is this CSS rule on the link:

```
text-indent: -999999em;
```

I have added an override for the site specific CSS to override this and hide the text by making it transparent.

With you in the next build.

Comment: Is this already live? Still can't click it in Chrome.

Comment: Very strange. Works for me on Chrome, windows 10.

Comment: Now it works for me too. Strange... I am on Chrome Canary, maybe something broke there in the meantime. Thanks.

Comment: Could very well be. That's one reason we don't support Canary builds (alpha/beta browsers).